# Was Hitler a necrophiliac?

Tags: adolf-hitler

In "The Anatomy of Human Destructiveness", Fromm claims Hitler was "a clinical case of necrophilia" in Chapter 13.

Is Fromme justified in this?

Is this a redefinition of the term Necrophilia?

Is there any evidence that hitler was obsessed with death?

Comment: I get a very psudoscience feeling from this, but it worth the ask. Apologies if the formats wrong or this is more suitable to philosophy or another stack.

Comment: What definition of the term necrophilia does Fromme use?

Comment: What sort of evidence would be convincing either way? Fromme did not conduct a personal examination of Hitler, and diagnosing celebrities without one is widely considered unethical. He spends a chapter on his own version of Freudian analysis to support his claim, but it seems largely unfalsifiable speculation.

Comment: That might be violating the Goldwater Rule

Comment: Godwin's Law *and* the Goldwater Rule.

Comment: @oddthinking I guess thats the problem with it, he makes a lot of statements about hitlers youth and I'm not sure about his sources on many of them, but mainly I'm interested in the validity of this sort of analysis.

Comment: @dawn, I think that 's one reason the whole thing feels so wrong. This question was prompted by a friend being convinced this is true based on the source, but after reading it I couldn't quite describe why it seemed so far off base.

Comment: @Brythan I wasnt sure how much of the source to include in the post because it might be a fairly long excerpt and paraphrasing it might be wrong.